# Inserción de datos de un array procedente de una BBDD MS Access en otra MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

A ver, ya he sacado con un algoritmo los registros de una BBDD de Microsoft Access que no están en una BBDD de MySQL. Ambas BBDD están en distintos servidores. Estoy utilizando como lenguaje de programación PHP. He cogido el array dónde tengo todos los datos y los he agrupado mediante el siguiente código:

```
$GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS=array_chunk($datosToInsertFromMS, 49);
//Otra forma que he probado
$GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS[0][0]=array_chunk($datosToInsertFromMS, 49);
```

Si yo realizo var_dump($GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS), los datos tienen la siguiente estructura:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        array(49) {
          ["Marketplace"]=>
          string(3) "WEB"
          ["IdPedido"]=>
          string(10) "PJSDJKSDKS"
          ["fecha"]=>
          string(19) "2020-10-08 00:00:00"
          ["nombre cliente"]=>
          string(23) "RONALDO NAZARIO DA LIMA"
          ["direccion"]=>
          string(16) "CALLE BRASIL, 23"
          ["DNI"]=>
          string(9) "89454081C"
          ["cp"]=>
          string(5) "13001"
          ["poblacion"]=>
          string(11) "CIUDAD REAL"
          ["provincia"]=>
          string(11) "CIUDAD REAL"
          ["telefono"]=>
          string(9) "876482913"
          ["idarticulo"]=>
          string(9) "PSJASJDJC"
          ["descripcion"]=>
          string(12) "BALON FUTBOL"
          ["peso"]=>
          string(2) "30"
          ["bultos"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["importe"]=>
          string(7) "20.0000"
          ["impporte"]=>
          string(7) "10.0000"
          ["totalpedido"]=>
          string(7) "30.0000"
          ["comision"]=>
          string(5) ".0000"
          ["idarticuloA"]=>
          NULL
          ["aceptacambio"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["fechasalida"]=>
          NULL
          ["Albaran"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["almacensalida"]=>
          NULL
          ["agencia"]=>
          NULL
          ["recogidausado"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["tiquet"]=>
          NULL
          ["fechatiquet"]=>
          NULL
          ["numserie"]=>
          NULL
          ["numeroseguimiento"]=>
          NULL
          ["MOBEL"]=>
          NULL
          ["idservicio"]=>
          NULL
          ["Cancelado"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["RT"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["OBSERVACIONES"]=>
          NULL
          ["sistema"]=>
          string(19) "2020-10-08 00:00:00"
          ["PedidoIndot"]=>
          NULL
          ["costeportes"]=>
          string(6) "5.0000"
          ["costearticulo"]=>
          string(5) ".0000"
          ["Estado"]=>
          string(6) "PEDIDO"
          ["proveedor"]=>
          NULL
          ["FPedido"]=>
          NULL
          ["FEntrega"]=>
          NULL
          ["Factura"]=>
          NULL
          ["FechaFactura"]=>
          NULL
          ["Validaciones"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["finalizado"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["cod_pedido_prov"]=>
          NULL
          ["agencia_prov"]=>
          NULL
          ["url_tracking"]=>
          NULL
        }
```

El caso es que al realizar la inserción en la BBDD de MySQL con este código:

```
foreach ($GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS as $row) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO pedidos (". implode(",",$arrayColumns).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$row)."');";
        }
```

me dice que hay un error de tipo Array to String conversion, pero no he sido capaz de detectar aún dónde está el fallo. ¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias, saludos.

P.D. La estructura del array original (el que tiene los datos antes de hacer el chunk, $datosToInsertFromMS) es la siguiente:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(49) {
    ["Marketplace"]=>
    string(3) "WEB"
    ["IdPedido"]=>
    string(10) "PJSDJKSDKS"
    ["fecha"]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-08 00:00:00"
    ["nombre cliente"]=>
    string(23) "RONALDO NAZARIO DA LIMA"
    ["direccion"]=>
    string(16) "CALLE BRASIL, 23"
    ["DNI"]=>
    string(9) "89454081C"
    ["cp"]=>
    string(5) "13001"
    ["poblacion"]=>
    string(11) "CIUDAD REAL"
    ["provincia"]=>
    string(11) "CIUDAD REAL"
    ["telefono"]=>
    string(9) "876482913"
    ["idarticulo"]=>
    string(9) "PSJASJDJC"
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(12) "BALON FUTBOL"
    ["peso"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["bultos"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["importe"]=>
    string(7) "20.0000"
    ["impporte"]=>
    string(7) "10.0000"
    ["totalpedido"]=>
    string(7) "30.0000"
    ["comision"]=>
    string(5) ".0000"
    ["idarticuloA"]=>
    NULL
    ["aceptacambio"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["fechasalida"]=>
    NULL
    ["Albaran"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["almacensalida"]=>
    NULL
    ["agencia"]=>
    NULL
    ["recogidausado"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tiquet"]=>
    NULL
    ["fechatiquet"]=>
    NULL
    ["numserie"]=>
    NULL
    ["numeroseguimiento"]=>
    NULL
    ["MOBEL"]=>
    NULL
    ["idservicio"]=>
    NULL
    ["Cancelado"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["RT"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["OBSERVACIONES"]=>
    NULL
    ["sistema"]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-08 00:00:00"
    ["PedidoIndot"]=>
    NULL
    ["costeportes"]=>
    string(6) "5.0000"
    ["costearticulo"]=>
    string(5) ".0000"
    ["Estado"]=>
    string(6) "PEDIDO"
    ["proveedor"]=>
    NULL
    ["FPedido"]=>
    NULL
    ["FEntrega"]=>
    NULL
    ["Factura"]=>
    NULL
    ["FechaFactura"]=>
    NULL
    ["Validaciones"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["finalizado"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["cod_pedido_prov"]=>
    NULL
    ["agencia_prov"]=>
    NULL
    ["url_tracking"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Deberìas mostrar el error de codigo ademas, para tenerlo mas en claro. Pero me salta la duda ese ',$arrayColumns' ... es decir, por que inicia con coma ??

Comment: Los datos están metidos en un array anidado, prueba esto: `$GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS=array_chunk($datosToInsertFromMS[0][0], 49);` y dinos qué pasa.

Comment: Salen nuevos errores. En concreto, salen: Undefined offset; array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given; Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: Espera, intenta así: `$GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS[0][0]=array_chunk($datosToInsertFromMS, 49);`

Comment: Creo que le has dado al clavo, @A.Cedano

Comment: Si no funciona, muéstranos un `var_dump($datosToInsertFromMS);` si es muy grande muestra un resumen, pero con al menos una estructura completa. Para verlo identado pon un `echo "<pre>";` antes del `var_dump`, así es más fácil de analizar.

Comment: Hecho. No funciona, pero antes salían 4 errores array to string conversion y ahora sólo uno, hemos mejorado :)

Comment: Sergio, pero no veo claro dónde habría que hacer el chunk? ¿Qué es lo que delimita cada fila?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que los datos están anidados. Debes dejar el resto de código como está, sólo cambiar el arreglo que se itera:

```php
foreach ($GroupByRegisterDatosToInsertFromMS[0] as $row) {
    // Itera la posición cero del arreglo
    // Te recomiendo usar la función "var_dump" en conjunto con "die" para depurar ciclos for, while.
    // var_dump($row); die();
    $sql="INSERT INTO pedidos (". implode(",",$arrayColumns).") VALUES ('".implode("','",$row)."');";
}
```

Comment: No entiendo esa fórmula, porque yo no quiero insertar sólo el primer registro de esa variable de tipo array, sino todas.

Comment: No, no es la intención insertar sólo un registro. Usa el tip de depuración que te he puesto en los comentarios, así sabrás exactamente qué datos existen dentro del bucle.

Comment: Pues no me sale error, pero tampoco me hace la inserción.

Comment: Para saber porqué pasa eso, necesitamos ejecutar esta línea: `var_dump($row); die();`. Si necesitas más ayuda, compártenos el resultado.

Comment: Finalmente me han cambiado la tarea y ya no tengo que seguir haciendo eso, pero tu respuesta fue de gran ayuda. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: ¡Para servirte!